# How to isolate a child with vector polymorphism

Tags: c++, vector, foreach, polymorphism

```
    class problem
{
public:
virtual void show() =0;
}

class wound : public problem
{
public:
void show();
}

class disease: public problem
{
public:
void show();
}

vector<problem*> lstProb;

// I want to show all wounds only, no diseases yet
for each (wound* ouch in  lstProb)
   ouch->show();

// Here only the diseases
for each (disease* berk in  lstProb)
   berk->show();
```

My issue is that at both "for each", all the problems are listed.
Is there a way to do that? I don't want to add a variable that identifies the sub-class.

Comment: You could use dynamic_cast.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use dynamic_cast in this case because you cannot guarantee the derived type that you have in the vector.

Something like this works:

```
template <class DerivedType, class BaseType, class F>
void for_each(vector<BaseType *> elems, F && f) {
    for (auto elem : elems)
        if (auto ptr = dynamic_cast<DerivedType*>(elem))
            f(elem);
}

//usage
for_each<Wound>(allelems, [](Wound * w) { ... });
for_each<Disease>(allelems, [](Disease * d) { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with polymorphism I've tended to use an enum identifier within the base class. The pro to this is that you can do simple integer comparisons to see if a Derived Type is that type. The con side is that if someone wants to add another or new derived type is that they must register a new identifier to the base classes enum.

Your code would then look something like this:

```
class Problem {
public:
    enum Type {
        WOUND,
        DISEASE
    };  

protected:
    Type type_;

public:
    virtual void show() = 0;
    Type getType() const {
        return type_;
    } 

protected:
    explicit Problem( Type type ) : type_( type ) {}
};

class Wound : public Problem {
public:
    static unsigned counter_;
    unsigned id_;

    Wound() : Problem( Type::WOUND ) {
        counter_++;
        id_ = counter_;
    }

    void show() override {
        std::cout << "Wound " << id_ << "\n";
    }
};
unsigned Wound::counter_ = 0;


class Disease : public Problem {
public:
    static unsigned counter_;
    unsigned id_;

    Disease() : Problem( Type::DISEASE ) {
        counter_++;
        id_ = counter_;
    }

    void show() override {
        std::cout << "Disease " << id_ << "\n";
    }
};
unsigned Disease::counter_ = 0;

int main() {
    std::vector<Problem*> Probs;

    // Add 10 of each to the list: types should be alternated here
    // Vector<Problem> should look like: { wound, diesease, wound, disease...}
    for ( unsigned i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
        //Wound* pWound = nullptr;
        //Disease* pDisease = nullptr;

        Probs.push_back( new Wound );
        Probs.push_back( new Disease );
    }

    for (auto ouch : Probs) {
        if ( ouch->getType() == Problem::WOUND ) {
            ouch->show();
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\n";

    for (auto berk : Probs) {
        if ( berk->getType() == Problem::DISEASE ) {
            berk->show();
        }
    }

    // clean up memory
    for each (Problem* p in Probs) {
        delete p;
    }

    std::cout << "\nPress any key and enter to quit." << std::endl;
    char c;
    std::cin >> c;

    return 0;
}
```